# Creating SQL view to recursively search a schedule table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to come up with a way of creating a view in MS SQL Server to automatically check for schedule conflicts in the same table. I would like to see if it would be possible to create a view that would add a column and list the conflicting reservation_id's

My table looks like this:

```
reservation_id - integer
reservation_start - datetime
reservation_end - datetime
```

Here is some example data:

```
1, 2016-07-21 06:30:00.000, 2016-07-21 07:30:00.000
2, 2016-07-21 07:00:00.000, 2016-07-22 09:00:00.000
3, 2016-08-02 08:45:00.000, 2016-08-03 09:45:00.000
4, 2016-08-02 03:00:00.000, 2016-08-02 09:00:00.000
5, 2016-08-27 02:30:00.000, 2016-08-28 03:30:00.000
6, 2016-08-30 09:00:00.000, 2016-08-30 09:00:00.000
```

So, I would like to create a view that would then look like this:

```
reservation_id, reservation_start, reservation_end, conflicts
1, 2016-07-21 06:30:00.000, 2016-07-21 07:30:00.000, [2]
2, 2016-07-21 07:00:00.000, 2016-07-22 09:00:00.000, [1]
3, 2016-08-02 08:45:00.000, 2016-08-03 09:45:00.000, [4]
4, 2016-08-02 03:00:00.000, 2016-08-02 09:00:00.000, [3]
5, 2016-08-27 02:30:00.000, 2016-08-28 03:30:00.000
6, 2016-08-30 09:00:00.000, 2016-08-30 09:00:00.000
```

Is this even possible, or do I need to create a temporary table to hold this information?

Comment: Why does 1 not conflict with 2 but 2 conflicts with 1? Also 3 & 4. Why does only 1 row state there is a conflict?

Comment: Sorry, one-track mind. I've modified my question above to show all possible conflicts in sample data.

Comment: If Reservation_id 1 conflict with 2 & 3, What will be the result?

Comment: Sorry @MahediSabuj been a long day. I fixed the example data sets, however, if there are multiple IDs that conflict, the 4th column would show all the reservations either comma separated, or a similar representation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [**Cross Apply**](http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2005/cross-apply-explained) and [**Stuff**](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=3934817c-1a03-4ac9-a0ba-55b2bfbaea0f&tkw=uses-of-the-stuff-string-function).

```
Select 
    reservation_id,
    reservation_start,
    reservation_end,
   '[' + cf.conflicts + ']' as conflicts
FROM yourTableName t1
Cross Apply
(
    SELECT 
       STUFF
       ((
          SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), reservation_id)
          FROM yourTableName t2
          WHERE t1.reservation_id <> t2.reservation_id
           AND ((t1.reservation_start BETWEEN t2.reservation_start AND t2.reservation_end) 
             OR (t1.reservation_end BETWEEN t2.reservation_start AND t2.reservation_end))
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as conflicts 
) cf
-- Where Clause Here like 'WHERE t1.reservation_id <> 1'
```

And If you want to create view with this query, Then here it is:

```
CREATE VIEW YourViewName
AS
-- Select Query Here
```

**UPDATE**

```
;WITH CTE_Reservation
AS
(
   Select 
    reservation_id,
    reservation_start,
    reservation_end
  FROM yourTableName
  -- Where Clause Here
)

Select 
    reservation_id,
    reservation_start,
    reservation_end,
   '[' + cf.conflicts + ']' as conflicts
FROM CTE_Reservation t1
Cross Apply
(
    SELECT 
       STUFF
       ((
          SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), reservation_id)
          FROM CTE_Reservation t2
          WHERE t1.reservation_id <> t2.reservation_id
           AND ((t1.reservation_start BETWEEN t2.reservation_start AND t2.reservation_end) 
             OR (t1.reservation_end BETWEEN t2.reservation_start AND t2.reservation_end))
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as conflicts 
) cf
```

Comment: Where would I place a WHERE clause in here to limit the reservation_start date?

Comment: you can write WHERE CLAUSE after cf (check the answer).

Comment: One problem that I see is that if my WHERE clause is selecting from a specific datetime, any event_id's that it conflicts with is returning a '[*,*,*,*]' in the conflicts field.

Comment: I'm still getting a comma separated list of asterisks in my conflict field.

Comment: If I add  WHERE reservation_start > '2016-06-01' into your update query, I still get the conflict column giving me the empty conflicts, however the date ranges it returns is correct according to the WHERE. If I take it out, I'll get the entire table, but the conflicts column is populated correctly then.  Here is a complete pastebin with output at the bottom: http://pastebin.com/PK7NPwhm

Comment: As I understand, if you use where clause then result will have those rows whose meet the condition but conflicts column check with the entire table to check conflict, is that right? is yes the updated answer wrong. But if you want to see those conflicts only which are meet the where condition also, then updated answer is correct. Let me know which one want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114271/discussion-between-photovor-and-mahedi-sabuj).

Answer (score 0):

Commented fragment - trivial join which will return required result but not aggregated (each conflict on separate line):

```
;with res as
(
  select 1 as reservation_id, convert(datetime, '2016-07-21 06:30:00.000', 120) as reservation_start, convert(datetime, '2016-07-21 07:30:00.000', 120) as reservation_end
  union all
  select 2, '2016-07-21 07:00:00.000', '2016-07-22 09:00:00.000'
  union all
  select 3, '2016-08-02 08:45:00.000', '2016-08-03 09:45:00.000'
  union all
  select 4, '2016-08-02 03:00:00.000', '2016-08-02 09:00:00.000'
  union all
  select 5, '2016-08-27 02:30:00.000', '2016-08-28 03:30:00.000'
  union all
  select 6, '2016-08-30 09:00:00.000', '2016-08-30 09:00:00.000'
  union all
  select 7, '2016-07-21 07:31:00.000', '2016-07-22 09:00:00.000'
)
/*
select r.*, r2.reservation_id as conflict_id
from res r
left join res r2
on r2.reservation_id != r.reservation_id
and r2.reservation_start < r.reservation_end and r2.reservation_end >= r.reservation_start
*/

select
  r.reservation_id,
  r.reservation_start,
  r.reservation_end,
  stuff((
    select ',' + cast(r2.reservation_id as varchar(10))
    from res r2
    where r2.reservation_id != r.reservation_id
      and r2.reservation_start < r.reservation_end and r2.reservation_end >= r.reservation_start
    order by r2.reservation_id
    for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '['
  ) + ']' as conflict_ids
from res r
```

final fragment will collect conflicts comma separated